# How to Track opens/clicks for a cloud page into a DE

Tags: marketing-cloud

I need to store the opens/clicks for a cloud page in a Data Extension. Can anyone please share some sample code for this?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please [edit] your question to include those details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, create a Data Extension containing fields you need to capture then use the AMPscript [InsertData](https://ampscript.guide/insertdata/) function to populate the required values into the DE fields.

In the example below, a Data Extension named 'Page Visits' includes two fields, Subscriber Key (text field) and Event Date (date field). There is no primary key on the DE.

Assumming a the Subscriber visits the page from an email link using the [CloudPagesURL function](https://ampscript.guide/cloudpagesurl/), the Subscriber Key and the date (based on the Business Unit timezone) will be inserted into the Data Extension when the page loads.

```
%%[ InsertData('Page Visits','Subscriber Key', _subscriberKey, 'Event Date', SystemDateToLocalDate(Now())) ]%%
```